# Apache Maven: Windows 7 64-bit classpath not recognized

Tags: maven, windows-7, command-line, path

Windows 7 does not recognize mvn as a command.

Environment variables:

```
M2_HOME:  D:\apache-maven-3.0.4
M2:  %M2_HOME%\bin
PATH: . . . :M2_HOME;M2; . . .
```

At a command prompt, entering  "echo %M2_HOME%" and  "echo %M2%" gives:

```
D:\apache-maven-3.0.4  and  D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin
```

Entering "%M2%\mvn --version" gives:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven Home: D:\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java Version: 1.7.0_03, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java Home: D:\Glassfish3\jdk7\jre
and so on.
```

Simply entering mvn --version" yields:

```
mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or file.
```

I have restarted Windows 7 to no avail. 
I am at a loss as to what is going on here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have changed by path entry to %M2% and it works.  I knew it was a simple error.  Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add %M2% to your Path variable

Answer (score 3):

You need to set you PATH to refer to `%M2%` instead of just `M2`, otherwise the OS is looking for `mvn` in the folder `M2`, not the path denoted by the value of the `M2` env. variable